# PHP function only getting last value of array

Tags: php, arrays, email, variables, sendgrid

Ok, so per RamRaider, i've included the entire function.  I'm always worried I'll end up mismatching a variable or including a typo when I make it more generic, so hopefully none of those errors.

```
function my_custom_popular_posts_html_list( $mostpopular, $instance ){
    $output = 'https://startofwebaddress';
            $weekday = date("N")-1;
            $excerpt = ''; 
                $popularPost = get_post($mostpopular[$weekday]->id);
                $popularPostUrl = get_permalink( $popularPost->ID );
                $featuredImgUrl = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($popularPost->ID, 'full');
                $popularPostTitle = esc_html( get_the_title($popularPost) );
                $popularProduct = wc_get_product( $popularPost );
                $popularProductLowPrice = $popularProduct->get_price();
                $excerpt = get_keywords_by_id( $mostpopular[$weekday]->id ); //most popular = 0, 2nd most = 1, 3rd most = 2, etc.
                $initial = array("oldterms");
                $replace   = array("newterms");
                $excerpt = preg_replace($initial,$replace,$excerpt);
                $commonName = str_replace("+"," ",$excerpt);
            $output .= $excerpt;
            $output .= 'endofwebaddress';
        //Get Key for second input
        $First_url = $output;
        $xml = new DOMDocument();
        $ch = curl_init ($First_url); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);//return xml
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);//ignore 
        $xml->loadXML(curl_exec($ch));
        curl_close ($ch);
        $TagName1 = $xml->getElementsByTagName('TagName1')->item(0)->nodeValue;

        //Email URL
        $EmailURL = "urlthatneeds&TagName1=";
        $EmailURL .= $TagName1;
        $EmailURL .= "restofurl";

    $text=file_get_contents($EmailURL);
    $res = preg_match_all(
    "/[a-z0-9]+[_a-z0-9.-]*[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})/i",
    $text,
    $matches
    );
      session_start();
    foreach(array_unique($matches[0]) as $email) {
    $url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
    $user = 'user';
    $pass = 'password';

    $json_string = array(
      'to' => $email,
      'category' => 'most_popular',
      'asm_group_id' => '1141',
    );
    }
    $params = array(
        'api_user'  => $user,
        'api_key'   => $pass,
        'x-smtpapi' => json_encode($json_string),
        'to'        => 'example3@sendgrid.com', //This should be ignored
        'subject'   => $commonName . ' Detailed Protocols and Products.',
        'html'      => 'A whole ton of HTML',
        'text'      => 'Text Version of HTML',
        'from'      => 'me@mail.com',
      );


    $request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

    // Generate curl request
    $session = curl_init($request);
    // Tell curl to use HTTP POST
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    // Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    // Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    // Tell PHP not to use SSLv3 (instead opting for TLS)
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // obtain response
    $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);



    // print everything out
    print_r($response);


    }
    add_filter( 'wpp_custom_html', 'my_custom_popular_posts_html_list', 10, 2 );

    function get_keywords_by_id( $post_id ){

        // Get post data
        $the_post = get_post( $post_id );
        // Get post_content
        $the_post_id = $the_post -> post_title;

        return $the_post_id;
    }
```

Hopefully I can simplify the problem.  $EmailUrl contains a string with all of the email addresses.  I parse it with the regex in the code to get all the email addresses out, and those are output in an array.

Per RichGoldMD (thanks for the suggestions), I moved session_start() outside of the loop, and eliminated extra variables to pass email directly.  When doing so, the function just sends an email to example3@sendgrid.com. Again, if I take the first 'to' attribute and change it from the variable, to a comma separated list, I get emails sent to the comma separated list.  However, when I try to input the array variable, or if I try to massage the array variable into a comma separated list (which was kind of what I previously had up), then I get just an email to example3@sendgrid.com.  If I change the first 'to' attribute to [$email, 'myemail@mail.com'], I get an email sent to myemail@mail.com and an email sent to the last email in the array, but no email sends to the other ~1500 email addresses.

Hopefully this makes a little more sense and sorry for the lack of context.  Let me know if more info would make this useful.  I'm also happy to make this a little more generic if it would make it more useful for other people.

Thanks!

Comment: one thing to note - using`echo` before `session_start` is a no-no and combined with using `session_start()` in a loop .......... not great. The problem might be clearer to all viewing though if you posted the code in it's entirety rather than bits n pieces

Comment: I removed the echo so that should solve that problem.  I've also posted the full code.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I'v identified the problem. Your foreach loop loops over your email array, replacing the `$json_string` value each time, only the last iteration's value is passed into the `$params` array.

I suggest eliminate the foreach line and end brace, and replace the $json_string thus:

```
$json_string = array(
      'to' => array_unique($matches[0]),
      'category' => 'most_popular',
      'asm_group_id' => '1141',
    );
```

i.e.:

```
$res = preg_match_all(
    "/[a-z0-9]+[_a-z0-9.-]*[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})/i",
    $text,
    $matches
    );
      session_start();
    // foreach(array_unique($matches[0]) as $email) { <-- Removed foreach
    $url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
    $user = 'user';
    $pass = 'password';

    $json_string = array(
      'to' => array_unique($matches[0]),  // <-- Corrected "to"
      'category' => 'most_popular',
      'asm_group_id' => '1141',
    );
    // } <-- Removed brace
    $params = array(....
```

--------- Previous answer follows -----

Definitely move session_start out of the loop (it's not the problem but it doesn't belong in the loop in any case).

If the api expects an array, drop the line with implode, and pass $email directly instead of massaging it into $emailAddresses.

The implode statement results in a string, but your comments indicate that an array is expected.

```
foreach(array_unique($matches[0]) as $email) {         
  $url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
  $user = 'User'; 
  $pass = 'Password'; 
  $json_string = array(
    'to' => $email, 
    'category' => 'my_category',
    'asm_group_id' => '1234', 
  );
```

...

Comment: @TomM0419 What is the value of $matches[0]? Is it what you expect? You can echo it or dump It to the error log with error_log(print_r($matches[0], true)) ;

Comment: I'm also wondering if send grid has a limit to the number of destinations in a single command - have you checked the send grid logs?

Comment: Awesome.  That set me straight and was really close.  If did unique_array($matches[0]) then the function returned an empty array and defaulted to the example3@sendgrid.com.  If I edit 'to' to equal `'to' = 'matches[0],` and then changed 'x-smtpapi' in $params to `'x-smtpapi' => json_encode(array_unique($json_string)),` then it works!  Thanks for the help.  Side note: I came across your link to cancerexpertnow.com.  I've got a similar interest with a different slant (PhD perspective to compliment MD Perspective) that I'd like to chat about if you have time.  Could you send contact info?

Comment: Glad I was able to help in some way.

Comment: Not sure how to securely send contact info - but my handle here is also my twitter handle...

Comment: @TomM0419 my email is richgoldmd attt gmail.com